# Convert epoch time to readable format in javascript

Tags: javascript

My epoch time is in milliseconds. I am using a javascript function below but i am getting wrong results. Hope someone would help me out.

```
 function() {
var dt = new Date(1427441622783);
var hour = dt.getHours();}
```

or I am using this

```
function(){
var dt = new Date(1427441622783*1000);
var hour = dt.getHours();}
```

expected result is 13 hours but i am getting
in first case 7 hour
 and second case 18 hours

Comment: Can you please add  actual result and expected result .

Answer (score 0):

your code is getting desired result **13**  please check once

```
var dt = new Date(1427441622783);
var hour = dt.getHours();
alert(hour);
alert(dt);
```

Check [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/162a6jap/)

Comment: I am trying to achieve this in using mongo db as my time is stored in database in milliseconds and i am getting wrong result